Why is a comma (,) being added to the questionIndex when I am using it again for the following svelte component?
I have two components, Question.svelte and QuestionList.svelte. The Question component has a clear button which will clear the selection of its options, which are radio buttons. The QuestionList component has a clear button which will clear all the selections.
When I iterate over the object and console.log it in the start, it shows the objects correctly as {id: 1, text: "....", options = [...]}.
When I try to log the index from the Question component, it gives me the questionIndex in the form of "1, " instead of just a number like "1".
I want to pass the index in the loop as "1" instead of "1, ". It adds a comma automatically.
QuestionList.svelte
<script>
  import Question from './Question.svelte';

  export let questions = [
    { id: 1, text: 'What is your favorite color?', options: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'], selectedOption: "" },
    { id: 2, text: 'What is your favorite animal?', options: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird'], selectedOption: "" }
  ];  

  function handleOptionChange(questionIndex, selectedOption) {
    questions[questionIndex].selectedOption = selectedOption;
  }

  function clearAllSelections() {
    questions = questions.map((question) => ({...question, selectedOption: ""}));
    console.log('Cleared all selections');
    console.log(questions);
  }

  function clearSingleSelection(e) {
    console.log(e);
    const questionIndex = e.detail;
    console.log(`Cleared Single: ${questionIndex}---`);
    console.log(questions);
    questions[questionIndex].selectedOption= "";

  }

  console.log(`QuestionList.svelte`, questions);
</script>

{#each questions as question, index}
  <Question
    questionId={question.id}
    question={question.text}
    options={question.options}
    selectedOption={question.selectedOption}
    questionIndex = {Number(index)},
    on:clearSingleSelection={clearSingleSelection}
  />
{/each}

<button on:click={clearAllSelections}>Clear All</button>

Question.svelte
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

  export let question, questionId, questionIndex;
  export let options = [];
  export let selectedOption = '';

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  // Function to handle option change
  function handleChange(event) {
    const selectItem = {
      id: questionId,
      selectedOption: event.target.value,
    }
    console.log(`From Question.svelte, changed ${questionIndex}--`);
    dispatch('optionChange', selectItem);
  }

  function handleSingleClear() {
    dispatch('clearSingleSelection', questionIndex);
    console.log(`From Question.svelte, cleared ${questionIndex}--`);
  }
  console.log(`Question Index from Question.svelte: ${questionIndex}---`);

</script>

<div class="question-item">
  <div class="question-section">
    <p>{question}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="option-section">
    {#each options as option}
    <input
      type="radio"
      name={questionId} 
      value="{option}"
      checked={option === selectedOption}
      on:change={handleChange}
    />
    <label for="{option}">{option}</label>
  {/each}
  </div>
  <button type="button" on:click={handleSingleClear}>Clear</button>
</div>


There is an extraneous comma in the attributes here:
<Question ...
  questionIndex = {Number(index)},

This is equivalent to:
<Question ...
  questionIndex="{Number(index)},"

So it should just be:
<Question ...
  questionIndex={index}

(It's already a number.)

I had no idea that the comma was also sent together with the data as prop. It's my first time using a frontend framework so I had no idea. Thanks ! (Feeling silly)
